# WINAPI: capture mouse click in a ListBox for adding new items

Tags: winapi, listbox, click, mouse

I have a Windows application with a ListBox inside a Dialog.
What I want to do is to get a notification when the user **clicks in an empty area of the listbox** and then **add an item** that I would get from a new dialog.
How can this be done?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Update1: I added subclassing, and now I get the clicks in Listboxproc.
But I only wanted the clicks outside of existing items, in empty part of the Listbox. How can I check that?

Update2: I tried to call LBItemFromPt() to determine if the click was over an item, but the function always returns -1.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ListboxProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, 
                         UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    // Listbox was clicked
    long x = LOWORD(lParam);
    long y = HIWORD(lParam);
    POINT p = { x, y };
    int pos = LBItemFromPt(hWnd, p, 0); // always -1 !!!!
    return TRUE;
} 
return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

}

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc (HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
 {
     HWND hListBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX);
     // Subclassing 
     SetWindowSubclass(button, ListboxProc, 0, 0);

     SendMessage(hListBox, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
     for(int i=0; i<nItems; i++)
     {
       int pos = (int)SendMessage(h, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) buf[i]);
       SendMessage(hListBox, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM) i); // item index
     }
 }
 case WM_COMMAND:
 {
     switch (LOWORD(wParam))
     {
           case IDC_LISTBOX: 
            switch (HIWORD(wParam))
             {
                 case LBN_DBLCLK: 
                 {
                     HWND hListBox = GetDlgItem(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                     int pos = (int)SendMessage(hListBox, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
                     int i =(int)SendMessage(hListBox, LB_GETITEMDATA, pos, 0);
                     ... do something with buf[i]
                     SendMessage(h, LB_SETCURSEL, -1, 0);
                 }
                 break;
             }
      }
}                
// but how to get clicks in the listbox which are not on an item?
```

Comment: Sub-class the control and handle `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

Comment: Have you considered adding a special <Add Item> item to the list box, and adding an item when the user clicks on it? Sort of like the special tab that many web browsers seem to display, to allow the user to open a new tab by clicking on it.

Comment: Of course, but I don't find that so elegant, since I have several such Listboxes and don't want an <Add Item> button for each of them.<br>
It is simpler if the user click on an existing ListBox item I get pos>=0 and handle this item, if he clicks outside I get pos<0 and offer a dialog to add a new item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `x, y` to screen coordinates:

```
long x = LOWORD(lParam);
long y = HIWORD(lParam);
POINT p = { x, y };
ClientToScreen(hWnd, &p); //add this line
int pos = LBItemFromPt(hWnd, p, 0);
```

Comment: Great! I was close before finding this solution by myself. Thank you!